# How I can configure apache mod_rewrite to use one or another project?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, drupal-8, apache2.4

I have two projects under the same domain:

- The project #1 is a website made with PHP 5.4 and is not running on any CMS.
- The project #2 is a Drupal 8.x to where I'll migrate URL-paths of the project #1.

The structure of my document root is:

```
/var/www/domain-name.com/
/var/www/domain-name.com/project-1/web/
/var/www/domain-name.com/project-2/web/
```

Here is my vhost apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain-name.com
  ServerAlias www.domain-name.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-name.com
  <Directory "/var/www/domain-name.com/">
    RewriteEngine on

    # Any URL-path that not matched use the project #1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(user|admin|ece|membersgetmembers) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) "/var/www/domain-name.com/project-1/web/$1"

    # Any URL-path that matches use the project #2 (Drupal)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(user|admin|ece|membersgetmembers) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(user|admin|ece|membersgetmembers)(/|$)(.*) /var/www/domain-name.com/project-2/web/$1$2$3
  </Directory>


  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <Directory "/var/www/domain-name.com/project-1/web/">
    RewriteBase /var/www/domain-name.com/project-2/web
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002"
    </FilesMatch>
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/var/www/domain-name.com/project-2/web/">
    RewriteBase /var/www/domain-name.com/project-2/web
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I visit URL of the project #2 (the Drupal) ex.: **https://domain-name.com/user/login** I receive this error message:

> Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use
>   \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks for any help and sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you clarify, specifically, what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Aaron,
I've an old web project with many URL and I want made a progressive migration of each URL to my CMS (Drupal). Now suppose when I finished work a inner page of an URL path I need that the user see the Drupal page using the same URL of the old project.